Метка [python-3.x] без [python]
Столкнулся с тем, что существует множество вопросов про python, на которых есть метка python-3.x, но нет python. Это нелогично, ведь если вопрос про какую-то версию языка программирования, то он про этот язык. Тем более в описании метки ясно сказано:

Используйте дополнительную метку python-2.x или python-3.x, если ваш вопрос ориентирован на конкретную версию.

Я предлагаю: автоматически добавить метку python ко всем вопросам с python-3.x.
Дополнение: это относится еще и к другим версиям python, а также к django

"Автоматически добавить" Если бы всё было так просто! Нам приходится всё это делать руками. На эту тему даже чат есть: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148414/ruso-

И что тогда делать?

Автоматически метки добавлять нет возможности. Можете добавить вручную.

А вручную тоже нельзя - вопросов очень много

@u111 как это нельзя?! Потихоньку, по 15 вопросов в день... за 3 года справитесь. :)

Ну не за 3 года

Будь моя воля, я бы убрал метку [python-3.x] совсем. Формально она нужна. А практически я не видел последнее время вопросов, где нужно говорить отдельно "это именно третья версия". Такие вещи подразумеваются.

Ну так убирай//

@u111, я и убираю в новых вопросах. В тех что мне интересны, убираю.

И еще есть [django]. Она нужна

А вот [django] может быть без Питона вовсе. Если вопрос касается контента, а не кода.

В какой-то момент, я думаю, можно будет вообще синонимизировать [python] и [python-3.x], будет просто общая метка [python]. Я думаю где-то после 2030 можно будет (как раз 10 лет после прекращения Python2 пройдет). Пока - скорее в старых вопросах оставлять как есть, новые править. Я когда-то сам метку python добавлял вручную, там где была только [python-3.x]. Но это тупая ручная работа, есть более интересные и полезные вещи, которыми можно заняться вместо этого.

@insolor, можно и так. Только мне кажется, что это нужно сделать прямо сейчас, а не через 5 лет.

@u111 в этом нет прямо какой-то сильной необходимости. По факту текущая ситуация с метками [python] и [python-3.x] никому особо не мешает, кроме особых перфекционистов.

А если выйдет новая версия python-4, что тогда делать? Нужно же будет первое время как-то отличать вопросы по разным версиям. Значит, метки с версиями нужны?

@AlexanderPetrov python-4 не будет (в обозримом будущем). Собираются сделать нумерацию версий вида 3.год, но 4 версии с ломающими изменениями вероятно не будет никогда.

@u111, по поводу ваших правок здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1105557/revisions. Метку [python-3.x] удалять не нужно.
